# Libgdx- Draw a line behind the pointer

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am new to Libgdx. What I want to do: When you move your mouse on the screen it is followed by an white circle texture. Now I want to make a line or a path (don't know how to call it) behind your mouse. This path should also be smoothly removed after about a length from 300px (something like it is in the app fruit ninja)

EDIT: It should look like a snake: [image: like this]

Answer (score 2):

LibGDX Finger Swipe

Take a look of this [wiki](https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/LibGDX-Finger-Swipe), this wiki properly explain Swipe effect in OpenGL ES using LibGDX.

You can also download [source code](https://github.com/mattdesl/gdx-swiper) for the same.

Comment: is there an other one, someone which is more a normal line which looses its opactiy?

Comment: Are you looking for these type of lines https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6mJrB21HGGk

Comment: No they should lose there opacity and go away after about 1 second

Comment: It's a bit like that

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using a [2D Particle effect](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-ParticleEffects)

Simply create a particle effect that has 1000 particles, a life of about a second, that is a white dot that goes from full white, fading to black. Set it to continuous and let this particle effect follow your pointer.

Comment: 1000 particles? I think I dont understand what you mean. At the end there should just be one particle effect which position is updated 60times/second?

Comment: Yes that's good but how to make a particle effect like this? It goes forever?! Can you upload something like that?